# Как реализовать bubble sort в связанном списке?

Tags: javascript, сортировка, linked-list

пытаюсь реализовать Bubble sort для связанного списка в JavaScript. Никак не получается сделать. Искал подобные вопросы, но находил в реализацию только на C++ или Java. Буду благодарен за помощь.
Внизу реализация списка.

LinkedListNode

```
export class LinkedListNode {
  public value;
  public prev;
  public next;

  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
    this.prev = null;
  }
}
```

LinkedList

```
import { LinkedListNode } from './LinkedListNode';

export class LinkedList {
  private head;
  private tail;

  addHeadNode = (value) => {
    const newLinkendListNode = new LinkedListNode(value);

    if (!this.head) {
      this.head = newLinkendListNode;
      this.tail = newLinkendListNode;
    } else {
      this.head.prev = newLinkendListNode;
      newLinkendListNode.next = this.head;
      this.head = newLinkendListNode;
    }
  };

  addTailNode = (value) => {
    const newLinkendListNode = new LinkedListNode(value);

    if (!this.tail) {
      this.head = newLinkendListNode;
      this.tail = newLinkendListNode;
    } else {
      this.tail.next = newLinkendListNode;
      newLinkendListNode.prev = this.tail;
      this.tail = newLinkendListNode;
    }
  };

  getByIndex = index => {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let count = 0;

    while (currentNode) {
      if (count === index) {
        console.log(currentNode);
        return currentNode;
      }
      count++;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Comment: Операция перемещения узла в новое место (а ещё лучше - обмен местами двух узлов) есть? всё, чего ещё нужно? Или у Вас допустимы операции только на концах списка?

Comment: Есть только операции добавления в конец списка и добавление в начало списка. Нужно сделать сортировку,  в обучающих целях выбрав для себя BubbleSort

Comment: Выберите лучше сортировку выбором, тогда обмен не понадобится, только удаление из произвольного места.